# How can I achieve core web vital speed indwx

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, litespeed, core-web-vitals

I have tried fixing speed index issue on https://www.martwebhosting.com. it's really a headache to me.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Try disabling the W3 total cache, and then enable both Guest mode and Guest Optimization from the LSCache plugin to see how it goes.

Comment: The only three Core Web Vitals metrics as of now are LCP, CLS, and FID. Speed Index is not one of them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.